# sequence of javascript events and problem of using variable as parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax

On the execution of onclick or onselect event which have more precedence. Is it possible to set the precedence. I want onclick to be before onselect.

```
    <select id='t1' onClick=Click(); onSelect= selectClick();> </select>
```

on this click() function is populating the values in the list. While selectClick is to select an item from the list.

**Problem: when I click on the dropdown list I get the contents of selectclick (I have alert so I see alert and see the contents being populated after 3-4 times clicking on the dropdownlist)**

Are there some other events which will be better for my application. I am making ajax call to populate the values in the dropdown and latter another ajax call on selected item. I want to send the index of the list in the ajax call url.

I want to use the **this.selectedIndex** to get the index of the item selected and then pass that as parameter in url in ajaxcall. Is it possible?

Kindly suggest...

Comment: Wat is ur ultimate aim? I think you want to get the index of selected item in the dropdownlist and pass it to the ajax function.It can be done at onSelect. What is the use of click() here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `onFocus` for populating select as user may use keyboard to take focus to the drop down. Within on focus handler, you can check if select has been already populated and if not then make an AJAX call. Its important to give some indication to use while AJAX call is in progress (for example, modal wait window or setting text such as "please wait, populating" in the select).

Comment: Thanks Vinay... actually even now I am having the same problem that onfocus even:w! ajax call is made before the onclick even

Comment: @Judy, what I was suggesting is that you should use onFocus and onSelect (no need to use click handler).

Answer (score 1):

You should attach the selection event to the `option` tags.

Here's a sample:

```
function optionClicked(optionObj) {
  var index = optionObj.parentNode.selectedIndex;
  alert(index);
}
```

The HTML for this is

```
<option onclick='optionClicked(this)'>Blah</option>
```

//EDIT

Vishnu's comment in the main post is probably right too, but I don't know what you have in mind.  You probably only need one event handler for this.

Comment: @ Steve: Thanks for the help... Can you give a look to the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162176/problem-in-getting-values-in-dropdown-list since the problem is I am not getting values on second ajax call. Thanks for the help..