# problem in populating the values an then selecting in 2 different ajaxcalls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having a strange problem. There are two ajax calls in the code. The first onClick I want to use to populate the list and the second onfocus I am using on select a value to make an ajax call to other jsp script. This code is just making the second call and not the first.
Another thing I want is to send the list index in the url of the second ajax call. I know how to select the index value (h=this.selectedIndex;) but I am not able to send it if I use it with this code as "http://*****/check/index.jsp&id=6&vid="+h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at event handler for your select

- onClick - object on a form is
  clicked.
- onFocus - window, frame,
  frameset or form element receives
  focus.

It shows that immediately after click event occurs, select control get onFocus event and thats why second  AJAX call always executes.

Why don't you try something like calling second method on onChange event instead of onFocus like:

```
<select id='t1' onClick="Click();" onChange="handleButtonClick();"> </select>
```

Comment: Thanks Asif for your response... actually i tried with this change but even now the second ajax is only fulfilled but the first is never... any other opinion?

Comment: Why don't you try to feel your select box via other elements action i.e. clicking on labels,button.?